# Obtener el número de parámetros y por cada parámetro, obtener el texto

Tags: bash, shell-script

Quiero que mi archivo bash llamado `myfile.sh`, lea el numero de parámetros que haya puesto el usuario, y que haga un `echo` del texto de cada parámetro. Tengo este código:

```
#!/bin/bash
for paramNum in $#; do
echo "$paramNum"
done
```

Y cuando ejecuto:

```
./myfile.sh parametro1 parametro2
1
2
```

¿Cómo lo hago para que en vez de devolverme `1` y `2` me devuelva `parametro1` y `parametro2`?

Comment: Usando `$@` en lugar de `$#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por convención de nombramiento de variables en la shell, [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) interpreta el `$` como un argumento.

Puede limitar la cantidad de argumentos

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2
```

solo estos 2 argumentos se mostrarán en el echo, cualquier argumento adicional no se mostrará.

En el caso del bucle, `$@` expande la variable de forma separada por espacios,

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in "$@"; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Y en cuanto a `$#`, se utiliza para acceder al número de argumentos pasados.

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in "$@"; do
  echo "$a"

done
echo "Cantidad de argumentos utilizados: $#"
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tus parametros no contienen un separador de líneas, sería muy sencillo en dos líneas de comandos:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Cantidad de params: $#"
echo "Parametros: $@"
```

Y al ejecutarlo tenemos:

```bash
/tmp/tests/so.sh hola adios alo
Cantidad de params: 3
Parametros: hola adios alo
```

Si quieres algo más claro para parámetros con espacios intenta con esto:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Cantidad de params: $#"
printf "Parametros: "
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  printf "\"$1\" "
  shift 1
done
echo
```

Donde iteramos sobre el array de parametros y cada pasada disminuimos dropeamos uno del array "$@" para disminuir en 1 el contador de longitud del array "$#".

Ejecutándolo resulta así:

```bash
/tmp/tests/so.sh hola adios alo "hola de nuevo"
Cantidad de params: 4
Parametros: "hola" "adios" "alo" "hola de nuevo"
```

O si quieres alocarte, podemos usar IFS para especificar separadores claros, luego usar las variables internas de `awk` para definir separadores de registros de entrada y de salida:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Cantidad de params: $#"
printf "Parametros: "
(IFS="|"; printf "$*") | awk 'BEGIN{RS="|"; ORS=" "}{print "\"" $0 "\""}'
```

Y ejecutando:

```bash
/tmp/tests/so.sh hola adios alo "hola de nuevo"
Cantidad de params: 4
Parametros: "hola" "adios" "alo" "hola de nuevo"
```

Comment: y por que `#!/usr/bin/bash/env bash` en vez de `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: /bin/bash busca EXCLUSIVAMENTE el comando bash en el folder /bin. En cambio, el comando /usr/bin/env es un comando que carga tooodas las variables de entorno definidas, entre ellas $PATH, y luego ejecuta la versión de bash POR DEFECTO, es decir, la que se encuentre en las primeras ocurrencias dentro de los folders listados en la variable $PATH. Por ejemplo, por defecto puedes tener bash 4 o bash 5, o un simlink de bash a zsh

Comment: Igual en tu consola. No es lo mismo escribir `$ /bin/bash` que `$ bash`. Mientras el primero te asegura que vas a usar el ejecutable `/bin/bash`, el segundo te dice que vas a utilizar el usado por defecto. Este "por defecto" puede estar definido por la variable SHELL, o pertenecer a algún folder de la variable de entorno $PATH, osea, `$ bash` a secas puede ser `/bin/bash` o `/usr/bin/bash`, o `/usr/local/bin/bash`, o `~/bin/bash`, etc, o algo listado en tu variable $PATH